# Проблема с просечиванием куки

Tags: java, cookie, tomcat

Куки то приходит то не приходит не могу понять в чем проблема - иногда с третьего или четвертого клика просечивается иногда с первого от чего это может возникнуть?
Использую томкат 6.0.26
вот мой код

```
public static String printOrders(String json) {

    ObjectMapper mappers = new ObjectMapper();

     try {

         RequestPrintOrders printOrders = mappers.readValue(json, RequestPrintOrders.class);
         System.out.println(printOrders.getuIN());
         if (ClientAViewCtrl.ex != null) {
             System.out.println("ex != null ");
             ((HttpServletResponse) ClientAViewCtrl.ex.getNativeResponse()).addCookie(new Cookie("uin", printOrders.getuIN()));
         } else {
             ((HttpServletResponse) Executions.getCurrent().getNativeResponse()).addCookie(new Cookie("uin", printOrders.getuIN()));
         }

     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Просечивается? Что это значит?

Comment: addCookie - это значит